# How to move files in Master branch to a folder in Master branch on Gitlab

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

I have some files and a folder in Master branch. I am wondering what are the commands to move those individual files from Master branch to the inside of the folder in Master branch.

Should I clone the Master branch from gitlab to my local first?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you have cloned the repository locally, i.e. you did `git clone git@gitlab.com:sume-user/some-repo.git`

Then you just need to move those files, commit and push those changes

```
git mv old/path new/path
git commit -m "Some commit message"
git push
```

`git mv old/path new/path` is just a short form for

```
mv old/path new/path
git add new/path
git rm old/path
```

or, in case you don't have other changes locally

```
mv old/path new/path
git add .
```

Comment: If we want to move all files of a specific type, we can issue `git mv *.ps1 PowershellScripts/`

Answer (score 5):

If your GitLab web has the Web-IDE, you can use it to move folders without local clone.
Click on Web-IDE on the repository main window.

Right click on the folder and select `rename/move` ( for example moving `src` to `old/src`)

Remember to commit changes

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be answering the actual question, which isn't about moving or renaming folders but about the best way of moving a bunch of files into a folder

Comment: This worked for me - nice easy soution. You just need to hit source control on the left menu and commit the changes.