# Moving all files/folders in a branch at once to a specific folder in the same branch - GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, file-move

In the Master Branch of my repository, I have a number of different files and folders. I would like to move them ALL into a folder called "Test Scripts" in the same branch.

I'm new to GitLab and have been trying to seek online resources to help me & I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55738240) post, however, from my understanding, using the  `mv old/path new /path` command requires you to specify the directory of each individual file. This will take a long time as I have too many files/folders. If there's a way to have all the current files and folders moved at once, that would make things a lot easier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to use Git or even the command line. Just move all of your files using whatever tool you want, and Git will detect the moves, and then you can commit the changes.

Comment: I'm really new to this platform so unfamiliar with what tools I can use - do you have any suggestions? I can't find a way to do it directly through GitLab

Comment: Oh...So you never cloned the repo locally? The "normal" way to work in Git is to clone a copy of the repo locally, make your changes there, commit them, and push them back out to the server (in this case GitLab). Maybe it's possible to do this sort of thing in GitLab directly without cloning- I'm not sure. I suspect it will be much easier on your own machine since you can just move the files using whatever tool you normally use to move files, depending on your OS.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now - so I will clone the repo and make all the changes locally and then push it back to GitLab! Thanks so much; this makes a lot of sense :)